# 1998 Ford Mustang jerks badly on acceleration after I shift gears

Tags: ford, clutch, mustang

When shifting my 5-speed from 1st to 2nd gear there's no problem, but when I go to press on the throttle after shifting I feel a jerk. I have adjusted the clutch cable after replacing the broken one. What would cause this?

Comment: Check your transmission mount.

Comment: Is this a new problem, since replacing the clutch cable? Does it occur in any other gears? It seems likely that the problem would be either with the clutch adjustment (not completely released) or with the mount as @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 suggest.